# Ping from wsl 2 to a vagrant machine

Tags: vagrant, hyper-v, wsl-2

I want to be able to ping from wsl 2 to a vagrant machine, the problem is that they are  in different networks,
How can i do that.

And If a use the wsl switch It doesnt assign me an ip.

Help

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute this in powershell

```xml
Get-NetIPInterface | select ifIndex,InterfaceAlias,AddressFamily,ConnectionState,Forwarding | Sort-Object -Property IfIndex | Format-Table
```

And select the ifIndex of Wi-Fi and Ethernet IPv4, and then execute

```
Set-NetIPInterface -ifindex SWITCHIDWIFI -Forwarding Enabled
```

```
Set-NetIPInterface -ifindex SWITCHIDETHERNET -Forwarding Enabled
```

It should work